# Reading from a CSV file and writing to a new CSV file using openCSV in java

Tags: java, file, opencsv

I'm writing a program which reads a CSV file and I modify some columns.After modifying I have to write it to a new CSV file with modifications.

I have done till reading and modifying but when I'm writing it to a new file I'm just getting a single row.I'm struck here.

Help me overcome this?

I'm using openCSV and language is Java.

My code:

```
CSVReader reader;
try 
{   
  File file=new File("/home/srinivas/Desktop/saicharan/Cardsmod.csv");
  if(file.createNewFile()){ }
  reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filename));
  String filewrite="/home/srinivas/Desktop/saicharan/Cardsmod.csv";   
  CSVWriter writer=new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(filewrite));
  String[] row;
  while((row = reader.readNext()) != null)
  {
    String str=new String();
    String str1=new String();
    for(int i=0;i<row.length;i++)
    {
      str1=str1+","+row[i];
      if(row[i].equals("Card Text Listen"))
      {
        String [] nextLine = reader.readNext();
        String [] nextLine1=reader.readNext();
        str=str+nextLine[i]+nextLine1[i];           
        c2.met(str);
      }
      if(i==11)
      {
        String[] rowwrite=str1.split(",");
        writer.writeNext(rowwrite);                     
      }
    }
  }
  writer.close();
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: done editing @sinhayash

Comment: More code! What is `row`, `writer`, and `rowwrite`? How are they created? Anyway, the problem is probably that you are closing the `writer` after the first row - there is `writer.close()` in the `if (i==11)` block. As you can see, it is a bad practice to put more commands in one line.

Comment: moreover, you're concatenating rows to the same variable `str` (or `str1`?) which means you've the lost the information which row is which.

Comment: I edited and put more code @JozefChocholacek

Comment: I edited and put more code @asgs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw you read and write to same file, so you should store all the row to a list and then init the writer after reader completed
Exp:

```
String[] header;
        String[] row;
        int index = 0;
        // processing the header;
        header = reader.readNext();
        for (int i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
            if (header[i].equals("Card Text Listen")) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        // processing data
        while ((row = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                if (index == i) {
                    row[i] = "new value";
                    break;
                }
            }
            writer.writeNext(row);
        }
```

Comment: I need to change the entire column under "Card Text Listen" @Ha Nguyen

Comment: so you read and write on the same file or write to another file name? because it will have different solutions

Comment: @kotlasaicharanreddy Then you have to find out the index of the "Card Text Listen" column when processing the first (header) row, and change its value when processing the next rows.

Comment: I want to it  write to a another file with modifications. @Ha Nguyen

Comment: @JozefChocholacek yeah, you're right. We have to detect the index of column you want to change first and then you can do anything from the second row.

So I think your code is not work properly when you use reader.readNext() on the loop.

Comment: Yes it is not working properly when I use reader.readNext() in the loop. @HaNguyen

Comment: I edited the code, please let me know if it is not your expected

Comment: I know the index of the column I want to change but how can I change it from second row. @HaNguyen

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best efficient way to do it

```
public void copyCsv(){
    CSVReader reader2 = new CSVReader(new FileReader(ADDRESS_FILE));
    List<String[]> allElements = reader2.readAll();
    CSVWriter writr = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(Path));
    writr.writeAll(allElements);
    writr.flush();
    writr.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the following application using Sham Khan's answer. Maybe it can work for you. It completely updates the line according to the id in the .csv file.

```
@Override
public void update(String tableName, Long rowId, List<String> values) {
    List<String> select = select(tableName, rowId);
    if (!select.isEmpty()) {
        select.clear();
        select.add(String.valueOf(rowId));
        select.addAll(values);
        copyCsv(tableName, select, rowId);
    }
}

@SneakyThrows
public void copyCsv(String tableName, List<String> values, Long rowId) {
    CSVReader reader2 = new CSVReader(new FileReader(tableName + ".csv"));
    List<String[]> allElements = reader2.readAll();
    allElements.add(Math.toIntExact(rowId), values.toArray(new String[0]));
    allElements.remove(Math.toIntExact(++rowId));
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(tableName + ".csv"));
    writer.writeAll(allElements);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}

 @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public List<String> select(String tableName, Long rowId) {
        PersonResponseDto personResponseDto = selectById(tableName, rowId);
        if (personResponseDto == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
        LinkedList<String> responseValue = new LinkedList<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tableName + ".csv")); CSVParser parser = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(',').withHeader().parse(br)) {
            for (CSVRecord record : parser) {
                long recordNumber = record.getRecordNumber();
                if (recordNumber == rowId) {
                    Map<String, String> stringStringMap = record.toMap();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> m : stringStringMap.entrySet()) {
                        responseValue.add(m.getValue());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return responseValue;
    }

@SneakyThrows
@Override
public PersonResponseDto selectById(String tableName, Long rowId) {
    PersonResponseDto responseDto;
    File file = new File(tableName + ".csv");
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); CSVParser parser = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(',').withHeader().parse(br)) {
        Predicate<CSVRecord> predicate = ((record) -> record.get("id").equals(String.valueOf(rowId)));
        responseDto = parser.getRecords().stream().filter(predicate).map(this::preparePersonResponseDto).findFirst().orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);
    }
    return responseDto;
}
```