# How to delete a specific row from a CSV file using search string

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I am working on java project where I have to delete a specific row from a CSV file using java. Currently I am using opencsv. I am trying to achieve the below scenario where I have to delete the 3rd row from the list and I have two strings as input.

String 1 : cat

String 2 : mars

[image]

I am able to get the exact row and its number with my current code. How can I delete this row?

Here is my code:

```
private static void updateCsv(String string1 , String String2) throws IOException {
    try {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(OUTPUTFILE), ',');
        List<String[]> myEntries = reader.readAll();
        reader.close();

        //Iterate through my array to find the row the user input is located on
        int i = 1;
        for (String[] line : myEntries) {
            String textLine = Arrays.toString(line).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");
        
            //here i am checking for the two strings
            if (textLine.contains(string1) && textLine.contains(string2) ) {
                //here i am able to get the count the row as 3
                System.out.println("Found - Your item is on row: ...:" + i);
                // how can i delete the row that i have now ?
          
            } else {
                //System.out.println("Not found");
            }
            i++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a line in a file and remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377279/find-a-line-in-a-file-and-remove-it)

Comment: @Abra Hi its for text files, I want this to be achieved through opencsv only

Comment: Same thing. You can't delete a line from a file in java. You can only make a copy of the file that does not contain the line you want to "delete". A CSV file contains text only which means it is a text file.

Comment: Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380618/update-a-row-with-new-values-using-opencsv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
List<String[]> filtered = myEntries.stream()
                                   .filter(entry -> !entry[1].equals(string1) &&
                                                    !entry[2].equals(string2)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("result.csv");
CSVWriter w = new CSVWriter(fw);
filtered.forEach(line -> w.writeNext(line));
```

You can't delete a line from a file in java.

In the code in your question you load the entire contents of the CSV file into a `List`. What you want is to write all the `List` entries to a file **except** the line that contains `string1` and `string2`.

According to the sample data in your question, `string1` is compared with column `B` and `string2` is compared with column `C`. Column `B` corresponds to the element at index 1 in the `String` array that contains a single line from the CSV file. Similarly, column `C` corresponds to index 2.

Using the stream API, that was introduced in Java 8, you simply filter out the unwanted line. The resulting list contains all the lines that you want to keep, so just write them to another file. After that, if you like, you can delete the original CSV file and rename the resulting file (which I named "result.csv" in my code, above).

Comment: this worked like charm! , I had issue with string operations i have resolved those , thank you